# Queries in pg_stat_activity are truncated?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using `SELECT current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;` to see the currently executing queries, but I noticed that the query is truncated. Is there any workaround or any other way to see the currently executing queries?

Comment: The 1KB limit was removed in Postgres 9.5. You can remove it if you upgrade your database.

Comment: @KevinBurke We are running server 9.6.24 and it's still truncated...

Answer (score 40):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET track_activity_query_size = 16384;
```

You will still need to restart the service for that to take effect

Comment: Default value is 1kB. Use `show track_activity_query_size;` to check the setting. Should show 16kB.

Comment: Did you pick this specific number for some reasons?

Answer (score 32):

PostgreSQL 8.4 adds the parameter "`track_activity_query_size`". The value will still be truncated, but you can control at what length.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative in the extreme case is to use the gdb debugger to attach to the process and print out the query.

See http://darthanthony.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/viewing-running-postgres-queries-and-what-if-they-are-too-long/

```
gdb [path_to_postgres] [pid]

printf "%s\n", debug_query_string
```

Comment: I like this method, but, unfortunately i get `'debug_query_string' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type`

Comment: This works on later versions of gdb: `printf "%s\n",(char*)debug_query_string`

Answer (score 7):

Starting from PostgreSQL 13 the maximum value of `track_activity_query_size` [is increased to 1MB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/13.0/).

The default value of `track_activity_query_size` is 1024 bytes (as of PostgreSQL 13-16).

Note that if a query is larger than `track_activity_query_size`, it will be truncated.

### With docker

If you use docker, you can configure your docker-compose file like this:

```
# ...
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgis/postgis:13-3.1
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "track_activity_query_size=1048576"
# ...
```

### Without docker

You can set [the setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-ACTIVITY-QUERY-SIZE) at `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` like this:

```
track_activity_query_size=1048576
```

If you don't find the `.conf` file at that path, you can determine where it is using this SQL statement:

```sql
SHOW config_file;
```

### Check/Test

Be sure to restart the database to apply the setting. You can use this query to check if it was applied:

```
SHOW track_activity_query_size;
```

If the setting is updated to your desired size, you can now see the effect of this setting on `pg_stat_activity` table:

```
SELECT current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Answer (score 2):

Get your `postgres.conf` file path using below command

```
psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'
```

Or you are using the root user then simply

```
SHOW config_file;
```

It will output something like

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf # Output of above command
```

then just edit the file using vim and change the below parameter to let's say 16kb

```
track_activity_query_size=16384
```

And restart your Postgres server

After that if you run `SELECT current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;` it will show you the more query but it will truncate till 16KB you can increase the size that you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can just enable statement logging in postgresql (log_statement), and check the logs.

Comment: Not really, what if the SQL statement is a perpetually running statement? (zombie postgres process) Then, since it never completes, you would only be able to see it runtime, by querying SELECT current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;

Answer (score 1):

If you run a Google Cloud SQL instance, you can configure `track_activity_query_size` in `Edit Instance --> Flags` section.

I personally set it to `32786`.