# Queries in pg_stat_activity are truncated

Tags: postgresql

Yes, I know there is a stack overflow question with the exact same name:

[Queries in pg_stat_activity are truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135266/queries-in-pg-stat-activity-are-truncated)

I set this value to 7168, rebooted the server, and verified it with `show track_activity_query_size`. It actually shortened the amount of text shown, its now truncating at 256 characters.

What am I missing?

Edit: My database is an AWS RDS instance (db.t2.small) runningPostgreSQL 9.3.6

Comment: RDS is a modified PostgreSQL that nobody except Amazon (whose staff are under strict NDAs) can see the source code of. So this could be a consequence of changes Amazon have made to PostgreSQL. It doesn't happen on my stock 9.4, anyway...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was using PGAdmin. The query actually was returning a larger value, but PGAdmin was truncating it and I was copy/pasting it from the column out. The solution (for anybody else having this problem) is to use Query -> execute to file. This will write the full results, which you can then look at in the CSV file that it writes.

Comment: This helped me greatly, thanks. It's frustrating that pgAdmin is truncating such vitally important information.