# The client 'psql' truncates values in a column of type 'text'

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I query `pg_stat_activity`. The column `query` is of type `text`. The queries can be very long.

The client `psql` truncates very long queries.

What should I do to see the full query?

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135266/queries-in-pg-stat-activity-are-truncated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncating display by default in postgres psql select statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875295/truncating-display-by-default-in-postgres-psql-select-statements)

Comment: see also https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/issues/1223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psql` does not. try running smth like

```
select lpad('a',3000,'b');
```

Instead it is limited in `postgresql.conf`, try:

```
b=# show track_activity_query_size;
 track_activity_query_size
---------------------------
 1024
(1 row)
```

According to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-statistics.html):

> track_activity_query_size (integer)
>
> Specifies the number of bytes
> reserved to track the currently executing command for each active
> session, for the pg_stat_activity.query field. The default value is
> 1024. This parameter can only be set at server start.